# Unable to render a Mustache template

Tags: javascript, mustache

I have a template like:

```
{{#items}}
    <div id="{{dataId}}">
        <p>{{firstName}}</p>
        <p>{{sex}}</p>
    </div>
{{/items}}
```

and an array of objects retrieved from server:

```
dataId : 128  firstName : 'john'  sex : 'Male'
dataId : 203  firstName : 'doe'  sex : 'Female'
..
```

I am trying to render it using Mustache template with `render()` like:

```
success: function(items){ 
    var template = $('#movie_template').html();     --- step 1
    var output = Mustache.render(template, items);  --- step 2
    $('#movie_template').html(output);              --- step 3
}
```

The problem is that the `render` function is returning blank string as output rather than rendered html (step 2).

Note: Printing the ajax result in console log, gives Array[12] as output.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are getting array of object, but mustache needs object to render your template. And you are updating the script tag which is hidden element, it would not display any html on the page. I added new div and working fine now. Here is the working [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/s83wLbrx/2/)

```
Mustache.render(template, {items:items});
```

Comment: Is there anything to do with the name items as I am directly getting it with that name as success argument

Comment: what is structure of the JSON object that you are getting form the server?

Comment: Check this and made the changes: http://jsfiddle.net/s83wLbrx/2/
JSFIDDLE makes the script tag empty so I added inline template and new div to display the result please find the changes.